# checking number of binary tree nodes with a value higher than root

Tags: java, search, binary-tree

Hi I have the following problem.  Given a Tree I want to be able to check the number of its nodes that have values higher than that of their root and nodes above them.  i.e. if a node has a value of 11 it will should increase the counter as long as it is higher (or equal) than root and all the nodes above it (so all values up to root have to be lower or equal to 11).  How to best achieve that?

thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: is this homework? just go straight right + 1!

Comment: is your tree structured specifically to answer this question? ie - is it a binary tree where left nodes are less than or equal to their parent and right nodes are greater than their parent? if so it should be pretty simple. if not then I'm not sure why you're using a tree in the first place. perhaps a little more contextual information would help you get a useful answer to your problem!

Comment: it is not a homework.  right now I only look for ideas (e.g. brainstorming).  I thought of mapping this tree to another one based on some criteria (maybe one proposed by Antony) but it is still vague.  Binary tree as it is now not structured now (e.g. every value can go into it).  I'm using tree as an exercise to practice;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [breadth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) tree traversal. At the end of each level add the node values (for that level only) in a hash table, which is used to make your counter comparisons.

```
                 2
            /        \
           1            3
         /    \       /    \
      11       12    4      5
```

Playout:

hashTable = {}

1. Visit all nodes on Lvl. 1
2. val = 2. Greater than root and all(hashTable)? Yes. Incr. counter. Add all to hashTable. Goto next lvl.

hashTable = {2}

1. val = 1. Greater than root and all(hashTable)? No. Visit neighbor
2. val = 3. Greater than root and all(hashTable)? Yes. Incr. counter. Add all to hashTable. Goto next lvl.

hashTable = {2, 1, 3}

.
.
.

count = 6 nodes greater or equal to all the nodes above them.